# MongoDB: Find documents where the values of two fields are among a list of known good pairs.

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have documents in my unique_contact_methods collection, in the shape:

```
{
  type: "...",
  handle: "...",
  other_attrs: "...",
  ...
}
```

And an array of dictionaries:

```
[{
  type: 'email',
  handle: 'jordan@example.com'
},{
  type: 'twitter',
  handle: '@jfeldstein'
}]
```

How do I find documents in unique_contact_methods whose type-handle pairs can be found in the array of good pairs?

Comment: How many entries are there in the array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do something like this, given the parameters you gave:

```
# I already created some sample data
>>> import pymongo
>>> ucm=pymongo.Connection().so.unique_contact_methods
# check out the data
>>> for a in ucm.find():
...    print(a)
...
{u'handle': u'asya@mongodba.com', u'_id': ObjectId('53d5d6f75d263ca62b3e6bd8'), u'type': u'email', u'other': u'foo'}
{u'handle': u'asya999', u'_id': ObjectId('53d5d7065d263ca62b3e6bd9'), u'type': u'twitter', u'other': u'foo'}
{u'handle': u'asya999', u'_id': ObjectId('53d5d70f5d263ca62b3e6bda'), u'type': u'facebook', u'other': u'foo'}
{u'handle': u'@jfeldstein', u'_id': ObjectId('53d5d71d5d263ca62b3e6bdb'), u'type': u'twitter', u'other': u'foo'}
>>> query={'$or': [] }
>>> aofdicts=[ { 'type':'email','handle':'jordan@example.com'}, { 'type': 'twitter', 'handle':'@jfeldstein'}]
>>> for c in aofdicts:
...     query['$or'].append(c)
...
>>> for r in ucm.find(query):
...     print(r);
...
{u'handle': u'@jfeldstein', u'_id': ObjectId('53d5d71d5d263ca62b3e6bdb'), u'type': u'twitter', u'other': u'foo'}
```

Make sure you have a compound index on `type, handle` (or the other order, depending on if you will ever be querying by just `type` or just `handle`).